# Rebar shell - passing config file

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm sure this will be so simple I will kick myself my asking but how do I pass erl args, like `-config {file}` to erl when calling `rebar shell`? I thought it would simply passthrough anything that didn't match it's own switches but not so.

Answer (score 3):

`rebar shell` doesn't appear to allow arguments, but it's basically the equivalent of the following command line:

```
erl -pa deps/*/ebin -pa ebin
```

If your project has no dependencies, you don't need the `-pa deps/*/ebin` part.
If you need extra arguments, just add them to this command.

Another alternative is to use the `ERL_FLAGS` environment variable to specify extra arguments:

```
ERL_FLAGS='-config my_config_file.config' rebar shell
```

Answer (score 2):

`rebar3` supports this directly now:

- `rebar3 shell --config something.config`, or
- Add `{shell, [{config, "something.config}]}.` to your `rebar.config`

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant modify everytime your rebar.config but you can use the tuple {sys_config, FilePath}.

```
{sys_config, "config/sys.config"}.
```

When you run the command "rebar3 shell", they will load the configuration placed in "config/sys.config"